# Problem while loading git repo file into Tensor flow.load_model()

Tags: python, tensorflow, github

I am trying to get the pre-trained saved models from git repository into python and load them as the saved models into the tf.load_model() to future prediction. All though I successfully connected and able to pull the repo contents but my doubt is how do I load the content files into tf rather then loading using path? If that's not possible how would I get the path of the repository file once after connecting to the repositories present in my GitHub account?

I tried to load the files as path, of course it cant read it. Looking for a better way of doing it

```
from credentials import *
from github import Github
import requests
g = Github("token for access")
repos = g.get_user().get_repos()
for repo in repos:
    print(repo)
    content = repo.get_contents(path)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(content[0],
                                   custom_objects=None,
                                   compile=True)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ContentFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can read it from a url.  I would have guessed you could read the raw bytes by using [`content[0].content`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/83d6e0719cb7bfee57af398f93a73516b62af5f2/github/ContentFile.py#L38), but that won't help either, because [`load_model`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9eac822bb2b3416f25398e44282125d0405d69ba/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py#L154) expects a file path:

```
if (h5py is not None and
    (isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
```

And if you look at `h5py` [docs](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#h5py.File), you can only create an `h5py.File` object from a filepath.

I would suggest writing the file to disk first, before loading it.  Maybe something like this? (untested)

```
from pathlib import Path

tmp = Path("/tmp/model.h5")
tmp.write_bytes(content[0].content)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(tmp, custom_objects=None, compile=True)
```